# 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource Bean instantiation via factory method failed;

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working with oauth2 in spring boot, I have a login and work fine but when I implement resource server, it doesn't work and I am getting some errors, my code:

class configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("cliente")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("password"));
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean);
}

@Bean("passwordEncoder")
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean("tokenStore")
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}
}
```

class ResourceServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/publica", "/admin").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
}
```

class WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("passwordEncoder")
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
@Bean("authenticationManager")
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManager();
}


@Override
@Bean()
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}


@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user = User.builder().username("aldo").password(passwordEncoder.encode("secret")).roles("USER")
            .build();
    UserDetails userAdmin = User.builder().username("rafa").password(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
            .roles("ADMIN").build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, userAdmin);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    /*auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder.encode("secret")).roles("USER")
    .and()
   .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("secret")).roles("ADMIN");*/
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}   
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.arnaldocastilla.auth</groupId>
<artifactId>com.arnaldocastilla.auth.1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-boot-backend-apirest-1</name>
<description>este rojecti es para hacer un login de practica</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Errors

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found 2 beans for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but none marked as primary
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.arnaldocastilla.auth.SpringBootBackendApirest1Application.main(SpringBootBackendApirest1Application.java:10) [classes/:na]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found 2 beans for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but none marked as primary
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found 2 beans for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but none marked as primary
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:136) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.lazyBean(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:157) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:189) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:121) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:269) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:201) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec3f88c7.init(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
... 22 common frames omitted
```

I don't know what is happening in this case, please if anyone could help me, I will be thankful

Comment: remove duplicate Authenticationmanager bean in class WebSecurityConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

```
Found 2 beans for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but none marked as primary
```

This is not a valid Bean configuration for any Spring application. In `WebSecurityConfiguration` you have configured 2 `AuthenticationManager` beans. As the error suggests, you can annotate one of these with `@Primary` but the ideal solution would be to remove one of these instantiations.

Spring will try to automatically inject the bean of type `AuthenticationManager` wherever it is needed - by having 2 of these beans, the application does not know which to use and therefore throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.